# Replacing "and" by "og" and "In"by "I" in references and bibliograpy using natbib

Tags: natbib, languages

Since I am writing in norwegian, I would like to chang the two words "and" and "in" into norwegian. "And" appears both in references in the text and in the bibliography, while "in" appears in the bibliography.

My document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, norsk, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
\usepackage [norsk] {babel}                          
\usepackage[round, longnamesfirst]{natbib}      

\begin{document}

If I have more than one author, the reference would be a list of alle the authors the first time i cite it \citep{fysdid}. 
The problem is that I can not have the word ''and'' in the reference when I am writing i norwegian. I would like to replace it by ''og''.

\renewcommand{\refname}{Litteratur}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
\bibliography{litteratur}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}


\end{document}
```

the bibtex-file:

```
@book{fysdid,
title= {Fysikkdidaktikk},
author= {Carl Angell and Berit Bungum and Ellen K. Henriksen and Stein Dankert Kolstø and Jonas Persson and Reidun Renstrøm},
year= {2011},
publisher={Manusutkast},
}
```

The result:

```
If I have more than one author, the reference would be a list of alle the
authors the rst time i cite it (Angell, Bungum, Henriksen, Kolst, Persson,
and Renstrm, 2011). The problem is that I can not have the word "and"
in the reference when I am writing i norwegian. I would like to replace it by
"og".

Litteratur

C. Angell, B. Bungum, E. K. Henriksen, S. D. Kolst, J. Persson, and
R. Renstrm. Fysikkdidaktikk. Manusutkast, 2011.
```

Comment: Did you tried the `babel` package with your language? It might be best to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which shows what you have so far.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a Norwegian compatible BibTeX style with `makebst`, but there's an easier way. Make a copy of `abbrvnat.bst` calling it `abbrvnat-no.bst`. In this file do a search of the strings `" and "` and change them into `" og "`; something similar must be done with `in`, I presume. Then call this new style with the `\bibliographystyle` command.

The new style should be put in a place known to the TeX system, which can be the working directory. If you need also in other projects you should consult the documentation of your TeX distribution in order to find the right place and the necessary steps to make it known.

Comment: Jeg synes at det er også nødvendig å endre "In " til "I ".  (For å være komplett, skulle ord som "Volume" også endres).  Med disse tre endringene, fant jeg 13 ord som skulle endres.  Filen er ganske lang (for lang for å inkluderer som et svar) men endringene skje på linjer 121, 232, 325, 475, 597, 598, 641, 644, 652, 688, 691, 694, 1111.  (Ellers send meg en e-post og jeg kan sende filen.)

Comment: @Andrew: Well, I couldn't say it better. :)

Comment: Sorry ... couldn't resist.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! I had to change not only "I", "and" and "volume", but also "pages", "Technical Report", etc.

Comment: @PESolberg Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank egreg by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, that's why I converted the non-answer to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another, very easy solution (as seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264422/60208)) is to add one line after invoking natbib in your preamble. Thus, for Spanish:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\harvardand{y}} % change 'author and author' by 'author y author'
```

Less trivial is the case where the style does not rely on `\harvardand` (e.g. abbrvnat.bst). Following advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272055/cannot-replace-harvardand) should do the trick in this case: duplicate/rename `abbrvnat.bst` and edit it by locating the `format.names` function. Inside the function, replace

```
          if$
          t "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * t * }
```

with (for Spanish)

```
          if$
          t "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " y " * t * }
```

Don't forget to load the edited style with

```
\bibliographystyle{renamed-abbrvnat}
```

Finally, I understand that the "in" component in bibliographies is Latin (as *et al*) and therefore needs no translation.

Comment: Does this work with the `abbrvnat` bibliography style, which is mentioned in the OP's write-up, or does it work only with the bst files (such as `agsm` and `dcu`) that are distributed with the `harvard` citation management package?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your answer, then, so that future readers don't have to figure out on their own what the equivalent of `\harvardand` might be.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion @Mico