# LyX reference problem

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, jabref

I'm having a minor reference problem. Im using LyX 2.1.0 on Mac and Jabref 2.9.

My problem is that when I'm making a reference to an article/book, etc. that have exactly two authors it says "and" between the authors, for example (Petersen, C. and Plenborg, T.).

Right now, I'm writing a seminar that has to be in my native language (danish) and therefore, I need to replace the "and" with "og". How can I do that? 
I have tried to change the language-settings in both LyX and Jabref to danish, but it doesn't work. Jabref is set to the ISO8859_1 encoding - I don't now if it has something to do with that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: JabRef itself and the character encoding used there doesn't really have anything to do with the matter. Are the authors separated by `and` in JabRef? When you say you've changed language in LyX, do you mean under Tools -> Preferences, or Document --> Settings --> Language. The former is irrelevant, the latter may have an effect, but I think it depends on the reference style you've used.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, been working on my seminar. But:
Thats exactly what I mean, Torbjørn. And, as you say, I seperate the authors by "and" in JabRef.
Right now im using the "Chicaco" form - I can't see how a change in form should be able to fix my problem..? Btw, when I select "plain", lyx replaces my references with ??.

What would you suggest me to to? I need to try something! :)

Comment: Exactly what? Tools --> Preferences, or Document --> Settings?

Comment: Yes - Tools --> Preferences, or Document --> Settings.

Comment: @Lars_CPH Hi Lars, consider using "@" followed by "Torbjørn T." for comments you want him to see (it gives him a notification). I think he's more responsible than I and will check back anyway, but often I forget which pending conversations I have and if I'm not notified I might forget to check back.

Comment: Oh, you tried both. ('*Yes*' is a somewhat confusing answer when asking '*either .. or ..*'.) You have at least two options I think: 1) modifying an existing style (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18042/586) or switching 2) to `biblatex` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148410/586). `biblatex` has 'internationalised' those strings, so if you set the language to Danish in Document --> Settings --> Language when using `biblatex`, the translation should be automatic.  (@scottkosty In general you're correct, but when only the OP and I have commented, I'm notified anyway.)

Comment: If you're unable to make it work I can write up a more detailed answer later.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh shoot. That means my comment messed everything up! Well, at least I learned something :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I think I'll try the biblatex solution :) - anyways, I'll try to fix it tomorrow (or sunday) and let you know if it worked out!

Comment: @scottkosty: hehe, you are not the only one who learned something from the mistake ;).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you want to take any action?