# citation format style change from X & Y to X and Y

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`.

I want to remove '&' from the citation and replace it with 'and'  (Ex: Instead of "Fama & French (1993)" I need "Fama and French (1993)").

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

`natbib.sty` sets

```
\renewcommand\bibstyle@agsm{\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}\gdef\harvardand{\&}}
```

for the `agsm` style; to get the desired output you need to redefine `\harvardand` (delaying the redefinition `\AtBeginDocument`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\harvardand{and}}

%just for the example; in your actual document you don't need this
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xyyzzz.bib}
@article{HacheEtAl2013,
  title={Experimental evidence for an ideal free distribution in a breeding population of a territorial songbird},
  author={Hach{\'e}, Samuel and Villard, Marc-Andr{\'e}},
  journal={Ecology},
  volume={94},
  number={4},
  pages={861--869},
  year={2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\cite{HacheEtAl2013}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{xyyzzz}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]