# Cannot replace \harvardand

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using `natbib` with biblostyle `agsm` for my references. I like to replace the "and" in the references list between author names with a simple comma. Redefining it like this had no effect

```
\providecommand\harvardand{}
\renewcommand\harvardand{ ,}
```

I tried editing the `agsm.bst` myself but with no success.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, as a compilable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to edit (a copy of) the file `agsm.bst`, you could proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution and make a copy. Name the copy, say, `agsmcomma.bst`. (Don't modify an original file of the TeX distribution.)
- Open the file `agsmcomma.bst` in a text editor.
- Replace *just the first* of four instances of `" \harvardand\ "` with `", "`. This should be the instance inside the function `format.names`. (I assume you're OK with `&` showing up in the authoryear-style citation call-outs.)
- Save the file `agsmcomma.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- Be sure to load the "new" bibliography style with the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsmcomma}
  ```

  Moreover, re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

---

*Addendum*: Here's a full MWE (minimum working example). It uses the `harvard` citation management package, since `agsm` is part of the `harvard` package. If you wish to use the `natbib` package, you should load the `har2nat` package: It loads `natbib` internally and "translate" most of the macros provided by the `harvard` package into `natbib` equivalents. Switching from loading `harvard` to loading `har2nat` will result in "and" instead of `&` in the citation call-outs; the bib entries will remain formatted with commas.

[image]

First, line 184 of `agsmcomma.bst`:

```
        { ", " * t * }
```

Now the LaTeX code. It starts with the setting up of a minimal bib file

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{jddr, 
  author = "Jane Doe and Dane Roe",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-4",
}
@article{jzjz,
  author = "Jonah Zapato and Jordan Zwicky",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 3002,
  volume = 5,
  number = 6,
  pages  = "7-8",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard} % 'harvard' package provides 'agsm' style
\bibliographystyle{agsmcomma}
\begin{document}
\cite{jddr}, \cite{jzjz}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just copied and renamed agsm.bst to the directory where my main tex file is located and changed the line with \harvardand\ in the format.names function to { ", " * t * }. After loading the new file with bibliographystyle and compiling it with latex, bibtex and latex nothing in the ref list changed. there's still "and" between the names.

Comment: @Kai - I'll post an addendum with an MWE (minimum working example) that shows the effects of my suggested edit to a modified version of `agsm.bst`.

Comment: thanks for the MWE. unfortunately still no success - it just stays the same. can I provide you maybe my fill agsm.bst?

Comment: @Kai - I sent you an email message with some specific suggestions on how to fix up the copy of the agsm file. (The problem was that the agsm file had already been modified, in a way that impaired the correct functioning of the `format.names` function.)